# Why does this trigger fail? It says invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00904

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ORDERS_MV
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND AS
SELECT * FROM ORDERS;
---------------------------------------

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_ship_receive
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON ORDERS_MV
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE ORDERS SET EXPECTED_SHIP_DATE = ORDER_DATE+5;
  UPDATE ORDERS SET EXPECTED_RECEIVE_DATE = SHIP_DATE+1 
WHERE SHIPPING_METHOD = '1 DAY';
  UPDATE ORDERS SET EXPECTED_RECEIVE_DATE = SHIP_DATE+2
 WHERE SHIPPING_METHOD = '2 DAY';
  UPDATE ORDERS SET EXPECTED_RECEIVE_DATE = SHIP_DATE+5 
WHERE SHIPPING_METHOD = 'GROUND';
END;
/
```

Comment: The error message would at least point to which line of code had the offending identifier.

Comment: Not the cause of your error, but that first UPDATE statement will update every row in the table - is that what you want?

Comment: @Jeffrey:  There is an orders table, and it does not have these three columns: expected_ship, expected_receive, and actual_receive. So, I altered the Orders table to add these three attributes. Now, for each new insert in the orders table, I have to make sure that the expected_ship, and expected_receive are updated automatically.

Comment: So I created the Orders_MV, and created the Instead of trigger that would take the information from the Orders_MV, and update the Orders table. But for some reason, its not working for me. Even though, I create the INstead of trigger on the MV, it tells me "cannot create INSTEAD OF trigger on tables". I also tried changing the trigger to BEFORE and AFTER, and when I check to see if the Orders table is updated when a new row is added, it is not updated. So frustrating!

Comment: Why is this view materialized? Querying a view that performs lookup on a table and only this table is not less efficient than querying the table directly.

Comment: @indolent, you still haven't provided the exact error message text (including line/col number); and you haven't explained why you have that very strange trigger or what you think it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle can see your table structures. We can't. I'm betting Oracle sees the problem in your code.

It should point to the first line with the error. If not, select * from user_errors;

Maybe your ORDERS table doesn't have SHIP_DATE (since the first statement talks about EXPECTED_SHIP_DATE).

Comment: I created the Materialized View, and when I tried creating the INSTEAD OF trigger, it says: "Cannot create INSTEAD OF triggers on tables". This is strange.

Answer (score 3):

Not an Oracle guy, but shouldn't you use

```
:OLD.SHIP_DATE
```

or

```
:NEW.SHIP_DATE
```

and

```
:OLD.ORDER_DATE
```

or

```
:NEW.ORDER_DATE
```

refer: [Oracle's trigger doc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm#i1025109)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry,Why not create o BEFORE INSERT trigger on orders table? when create BEFORE INSERT trigger,if add a new row in orders table,Can use .NEW.EXPECTED_SHIP_DATE,.NEW.EXPECTED_RECEIVE_DATE update orders table. Don't create materialized view on orders